# What is the procedure to get answer from police related to a case?

Tags: criminal-law, india

My Father was murdered by a bullet to the head using Desi katta (country-made gun). He was a business man. I saw this all this in front of my eyes. The reason he was murdered was a property dispute.

I filed a FIR. I saw the person who committed the crime and know who he is. So the FIR was filled along with the name of the primary culprit.

The culprit is a person who is very much involved in illegal activities and all his money is black money.  As soon as he committed this crime he went on the run. Police are searching for him. 3 months are already over and the police haven't found him. But the thing is his businesses are running fine. He is constantly in touch of his people (workers and all). He is constantly sending letters to police in which he tries to proves his innocence.

Police told us that they are with us and they will help and they will catch him soon. But instead of catching him, police officials are going to verify the evidences which he is sending in order to prove that he was not present at the spot where the crime was committed(As I was present there and I had seen him and the shooter). What I think is, he is out there forging and creating fake evidences and police is with him. Therefore, I want to know
What legal procedures can I use to question the Inspecting Officer about the case and their efforts?

Answer (score 2):

At least in the U.S., criminal investigations are privileged.  The victims of a crime do not have a special right to information while an investigation is open; all information made public is done so at the discretion of the investigating officers.  Only once an investigation is closed is there considered to be a public right to know the results of the investigation, and even then many "work-product" details can be withheld from the public.

Unless India has much more liberal "right-to-know" laws (which I doubt) the only  means by which you can obtain information is by appealing to the sympathies of the investigators and convincing them that whatever information you seek will not jeopardize their investigation.

Only if you suspect and can provide compelling evidence of corruption or gross incompetence could you appeal an investigator's discretion to another law enforcement agency, or to a court.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about your loss.  No matter what, you will not get your father back.  As far as restitution for you and your family goes, a civil case will be the most effective method as this guy sounds like he is in business.  Contact a civil attorney ASAP and have them begin that process soon so that properties and monies are not shifted/hidden away.

The criminal case will come but the civil case can begin immediately.  Your life will be unaffected by his conviction and incarceration.  None of that will provide you relief.  Taking his money is what you can do.

Comment: No, I wont get my father back. But I can't sleep until he is behind the bars. My father was good man and he only mistake was 'he was doing good and fighting for the weak' . Right now I feel like -'People who do good are fools'. I don't want to turn myself into a monster. I don't even want to go for necessary evil. I want to walk on the path of my father i.e 'Do good no matter what' .